# How do I get an unique ID per class extention?

Tags: java, comparison, identity

I have a class with many extended subclasses:

```
class FirstImplementation extends Mother { [...]
class SecondImplementation extends Mother { [...]
class ThirdImplementation extends Mother { [...]
```

What I am trying to do is a simple and light way to know if two instances of `Mother` class have the same implementation:

```
Mother   a = new FirstImplementation();
Mother   b = new SecondImplementation();
Mother   c = new FirstImplementation();

a.sameKindOf(b); // return false;
a.sameKindOf(c); // return true;
```

My idea is to set an integer ID field in each `Mother` instance, and just compare it in `sameKindOf` function:

```
public class Mother {
    private final int ID;

    protected Mother(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return this.ID;
    }

    public boolean sameKindOf(Mother other) {
        return this.ID == other.getID();
    }
}
```

Every extension of `Mother` shall call Mother's constructor with a precise ID.

My question is: is there a way to automatically give a different ID each time I create a new extension, or do I have to do it myself, giving a different number in each constructor class?

If not, is there a simpler way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: In this specific situation you couldn't use `instanceof`anyway. You could, however, do `a.getClass() == b.getClass()`.

Comment: If you don't want to use instanceof operator why don't use then class comparison.       `return this.getClass() == other.getClass();`

Comment: @TeemuIlmonen Would it be as fast as an integer comparison? If yes, repost your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I would not expect it to be slower. The answer is already essentially listed below so I won't duplicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldnt

```
public boolean sameKindOf(Mother other) {
    return this.getClass().equals(other.getClass());
}
```

do the job ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested only in ID-style solution... Try to use the following mechanism:

In your `Mother` class declare `protected static int childClassesNumber;`. It will store the number of all unique childs were loaded:

```
class Mother {
  protected static int childClassesNumber = 0;
  private final int ID;

  protected Mother(int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
  }

  public int getID() {
    return this.ID;
  }

  public boolean sameKindOf(Mother other) {
    return this.ID == other.getID();
  }
}
```

Then, to assure each child gets unique ID, you should use something like this in each child (and this is not good):

```
class ChildOne extends Mother {
  public static final int ID;

  static {
    ID = ++Mother.childClassesNumber;
  }

  public ChildOne() {
    super(ID);
  }
}
```

The ID will be given only at class loading stage (only one time)

And (for example) `ChildTwo`:

```
class ChildTwo extends Mother {
  public static final int ID;

  static {
    ID = ++Mother.childClassesNumber;
  }

  public ChildTwo() {
    super(ID);
  }
}
```

After that, the following code

```
System.out.println(new ChildOne().sameKindOf(new ChildOne()));
System.out.println(new ChildOne().sameKindOf(new ChildTwo()));
```

gets:

> true
>
> false

This mechanism has a huge drawback - you should put the `static` initialization in each child. The boilerplate code and so on and so forth... so I would recommend you use @Ash solution )

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `java.util.UUID` class and its static factory method `public static UUID nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[] name)`. Is that what you are looking for?